# Print all paths of binary tree

Tags: python, memory

Given a complete binary tree (every node has 1 left and 1 right child), write an algorithm to print all root to leaf paths.

Here's a recursive algorithm in Python:

```
def print_tree(root):
  dfs(root, '')

def dfs(root, path):
  path += root.value
  if not root.right and not root.left:
     print path
     return
  if root.left:    
     dfs(root.left,path)
  if root.right:
     dfs(root.right,path)
```

A rough analysis of space complexity is: 
O(log(N)) on stack frame (max number of recusive calls is depth of tree)
O(log(N)) on heap (max number of string constructions is also depth of tree, given path is a string which is immutable in python).

The harder question is: describe total memory usage at the a leaf node.

So, at a leaf node, we'll have log(N) of function pointers on the call stack. But how many 'copies' or memory allocations exist for `path`? I contend there are also log(N) such copies, as path is not being garbage collected until each of its calling function returns.

So, at a leaf node, we have log(N) + log(N) of total memory complexity. Is that accurate?

Comment: I'm curious to know the answer as well. What are the memory tools are you using? What about `python -m memory_profiler filename.py` https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/